# apply indirect arrayformula to the entire column in gsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I get address of non-null cells from the formula below.

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="","",ArrayFormula(address(1,(mmult(isnumber(find("",A2:O99999))*1,sign(row(1:15))))))))
```

And I want values at the address I get from the formula.
What should I add to the formula to get those values?

I want to insert the formula to "laststatus"

| id | laststatus | ... | statusA | statusB | statusC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | statusC | ... | done | done | done |
| B | statusA | ... | done |  |  |
| C | statusB | ... | done | done |  |
| D | statusC | ... | done | done | done |

Thanks.

Comment: Excel is not the same as Google Sheets. If you don't use Excel, don't tag with Excel. The `arrayformula` function does not exist in Excel.

Comment: You can use `INDIRECT()` function like `=INDIRECT(arrayformula(if(A2:A="","",ArrayFormula(address(1,(mmult(isnumber(find("",A2:O99999))*1,sign(row(1:15)))))))))`

Comment: @Harun24hr thanks for your comment. i alreay know that it returns the result only in a column filled with the formula. I want the result in each row.

Comment: Hi @AokiSJSeonokYang, could you provide a sample sheet and include the expected values?

Comment: @AokiSJSeonokYang It would better if you share a dummy workbook for our clear understanding. Simply show your input data and desired output.

Comment: added a table. please refer to it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("×"&
 IF(D2:F="done", D1:F1, )),,9^9)),"([^×]*)[×\s]*$"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! I would appreciate if you could me tell me what's happening in the formula!

Comment: @AokiSJSeonokYang sure. IF range D2:F contains "done" we print labels from row 1  (D1:F1). if there is no "done" we leave it empty. then we add unique symbol × in front of it. next we use combo of FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE where we smash all columns into one single column from which we REGEXEXTRACT the last $ value from the string followed by our unique symbol ×. INDEX is there to process things instead of ARRAYFORMULA - just because its shorter

Comment: @AokiSJSeonokYang, If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("|"&IF(C2:E5="done",$C$1:$E$1, "")),,COLUMNS(C2:E5))),"([^|]*)[|\s]*$"))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72698323/17842569