# Getting last non-empty column on each row Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this data as output from an `ARRAYFORMULA`:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | test2 | test3 |
| test1 |  |  |
| test1 | test2 |  |
| test1 | test2 | test3 |

And would like to have this output:

| D |
| --- |
| test3 |
| test1 |
| test2 |
| test3 |

How do I get the output above? Having issues with using `INDEX` and can only pass a single column. If I pass 3 as the column parameter, it will get blank cells on the 2nd and 3rd row. I'm not sure how to proceed after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an arrayformula to do this in a single go:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("|"&A1:C),,COLUMNS(A1:C))),"([^|]*)[|\s]*$"))
```

---

**Note:** I assumed that *"Getting last non-empty column on each row..."* meant not all previous column are populated.

Answer (score 2):

In general rules of formula you can user below formula-

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$4,ROW(A1),COUNTA(A1:C1))
```

[image]

Comment: does that works for you ?

Comment: Yes, but need to drag the formula to each cell manually.

Comment: No, even if you drag, it doesn't work, these 2 others could work `=INDEX($A$1:$C$4,row(A1),COUNTA(A1:C1))`or `=INDEX(A1:C1,1,COUNTA(A1:C1))` if you drag

Comment: @MikeSteelson Sorry! I got your point. Co-incidentally result is same, that is reason  we got correct result. I have corrected it.